# How can I connect MySQL with using socket programming in C++

Tags: c++, mysql, sockets

I am newbie in programming world. I am trying to make Login system with C++ so I try to connect MySQL database with my server program. without using socket I can connect with database well. But my Final Goal  is to success login to my local server and add information to my DB.

I found that if I add "driver.h" from MySQL Connector 8.0, It said the connection is gone. actually it cant connect to socket. but when I comment out the "driver.h" hearder, It connect to socket well. but without "driver.h", I cant connect to my DB.

What is the problem and How can I solve it? the version of VS is 2022, and MySQL version is 8.0.30. Below is my full Code of Client and Server.

And sorry I cant emebed image still I am newbie here
[So I post in Notion][1]:https://sunny-green-970.notion.site/Error-ea96fbef0ea64e1bb1fd966699657547

```
Client
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddrIn;
    memset(&ServerAddrIn, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    ServerAddrIn.sin_family = PF_INET;
    ServerAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    ServerAddrIn.sin_port = htons(1234);

    printf("client\n");

    if (connect(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddrIn, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == SOCKET_ERROR) // 자기 ip와 port 필요없다. 서버에 접속하면 된다.
    {
        std::cout << "Connect Failed." << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    int Numnber = 0;
    int WinCount = 0;
    int TotalGamePlay = 0;

    //connect(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddrIn, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    printf("Please Type Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &Numnber);
    printf("Please Type WinCount: ");
    scanf("%d", &WinCount);
    printf("Please Type TotalGamePlay: ");
    scanf("%d", &TotalGamePlay);

    

    char Buffer[1024] = { 0, };

    memcpy(Buffer, &Numnber, 4);
    memcpy(&Buffer[4], &WinCount, 4);
    memcpy(&Buffer[8], &TotalGamePlay, 4);

    int SentLength = send(ServerSocket, Buffer, 12, 0);
    printf("Sent Length : %d\n", SentLength);

    if (SentLength == 0)
    {
        //연결 종료s
        std::cout << "Disconnected Client." << std::endl;
    }
    else if (SentLength < 0)
    {
        //Error
        std::cout << "Disconnected Client By Error : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

```
Server
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "jdbc/mysql_connection.h"
#include "jdbc/cppconn/exception.h"
#include "jdbc/cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "jdbc/cppconn/statement.h"
#include "jdbc/cppconn/prepared_statement.h"
#include "jdbc/cppconn/driver.h"


#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment(lib, "debug/mysqlcppconn.lib")
#else
#pragma comment(lib, "mysqlcppconn.lib")
#endif 

using namespace std;

std::string Utf8ToMultiByte(std::string utf8_str);

int main()
{
    bool bRunning = true;
    
    WSAData wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    SOCKADDR_IN ServerAddrIn;
    memset(&ServerAddrIn, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    ServerAddrIn.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddrIn.sin_port = htons(1234);
    ServerAddrIn.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    fd_set Original;
    fd_set CopyReads;
    timeval Timeout;
    Timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    Timeout.tv_usec = 10;

    FD_ZERO(&Original);
    FD_SET(ServerSocket, &Original);

    bind(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddrIn, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    listen(ServerSocket, 0);
    printf("Server\n");

    while (bRunning)
    {
        CopyReads = Original;

        //polling
        int fd_num = select(0, &CopyReads, 0, 0, &Timeout);

        if (fd_num == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (fd_num == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            bRunning = false;
            break;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < Original.fd_count; ++i)
        {
            //등록한 소켓 리스트 중에 이벤트 발생 했음
            if (FD_ISSET(Original.fd_array[i], &CopyReads))
            {
                if (Original.fd_array[i] == ServerSocket)
                {
                    //서버 소켓에 이벤트가 발생함, 연결 요청
                    SOCKADDR_IN ClientSockAddrIn;
                    memset((char*)&ClientSockAddrIn, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
                    int ClientSockAddrInSize = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
                    SOCKET ClientSocket = accept(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ClientSockAddrIn, &ClientSockAddrInSize);
                    FD_SET(ClientSocket, &Original);
                    std::cout << "Connected client : " << ClientSocket << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    SOCKET ClientSocket = Original.fd_array[i];
                    //Client 소켓, Recv, Send
                    char Buffer[1024] = { 0, };

                    //blocking, non blocking
                    //packet 설계, protocol 
                    int RecvLength = recv(ClientSocket, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0);

                    if (RecvLength == 0)
                    {
                        //연결 종료
                        std::cout << "Disconnected Client." << std::endl;
                        FD_CLR(ClientSocket, &Original);
                        closesocket(ClientSocket);
                    }
                    else if (RecvLength < 0)
                    {
                        //Error
                        std::cout << "Disconnected Client By Error : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                        FD_CLR(ClientSocket, &Original);
                        closesocket(ClientSocket);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //자료가 있으면 처리
                        //packet parse
                        int number = 0;
                        int wincount = 0;
                        int totalgameplay = 0;

                        memcpy(&number, &buffer[0], 4);
                        memcpy(&wincount, &buffer[4], 4);
                        memcpy(&totalgameplay, &buffer[8], 4);

                        try
                        {
                            sql::driver* driver; //workbench
                            sql::connection* connection; //접속
                            sql::statement* statement; //query
                            sql::resultset* resultset; //결과화면
                            sql::preparedstatement* preparedstatement;

                            //work벤치 켜기
                            driver = get_driver_instance();

                            //연결 버튼 누르기
                            connection = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "secret");

                            if (connection == nullptr)
                            {
                                cout << "connect failed" << endl;
                                exit(-1);
                            }

                            사용 데이터베이스 선정(use)
                            connection->setschema("logindata");

                            preparedstatement = connection->preparestatement("insert into new_table(number, wincount, totalgameplay) values( ?, ? ,?)");
                            preparedstatement->setint(1, number);
                            preparedstatement->setint(2, wincount);
                            preparedstatement->setint(3, totalgameplay);
                            preparedstatement->executeupdate();

                            statement = connection->createstatement();
                            resultset = statement->executequery("select * from new_table ");

                            for (;resultset->next();)
                            {
                                cout << resultset->getint("number") << " : " <<
                                    utf8tomultibyte(resultset->getstring("wincount")) << " : " <<
                                    utf8tomultibyte(resultset->getstring("totalgameplay")) << endl;
                            }

                            delete resultset;
                            delete preparedstatement;
                            delete connection;
                        }
                        catch (sql::sqlexception e)
                        {
                            cout << "# err: sqlexception in " << __file__;
                            cout << "(" << __function__ << ") on line " << __line__ << endl;
                            cout << "# err: " << e.what();
                            cout << " (mysql error code: " << e.geterrorcode();
                            cout << ", sqlstate: " << e.getsqlstate() << " )" << endl;
                        }


                        /*for (size_t i = 0; i < original.fd_count; ++i)
                        {
                            if (original.fd_array[i] != serversocket)
                            {
                                std::cout << original.fd_array[i] << std::endl;
                                int sentlength = send(original.fd_array[i], buffer, 8, 0);
                            }
                        }*/

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(ServerSocket);

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}

std::string Utf8ToMultiByte(std::string utf8_str)
{
    std::string resultString; char* pszIn = new char[utf8_str.length() + 1];
    strncpy_s(pszIn, utf8_str.length() + 1, utf8_str.c_str(), utf8_str.length());
    int nLenOfUni = 0, nLenOfANSI = 0; wchar_t* uni_wchar = NULL;
    char* pszOut = NULL;
    // 1. utf8 Length
    if ((nLenOfUni = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszIn, (int)strlen(pszIn), NULL, 0)) <= 0)
        return nullptr;
    uni_wchar = new wchar_t[nLenOfUni + 1];
    memset(uni_wchar, 0x00, sizeof(wchar_t) * (nLenOfUni + 1));
    // 2. utf8 --> unicode
    nLenOfUni = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, pszIn, (int)strlen(pszIn), uni_wchar, nLenOfUni);
    // 3. ANSI(multibyte) Length
    if ((nLenOfANSI = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, uni_wchar, nLenOfUni, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)) <= 0)
    {
        delete[] uni_wchar; return 0;
    }
    pszOut = new char[nLenOfANSI + 1];
    memset(pszOut, 0x00, sizeof(char) * (nLenOfANSI + 1));
    // 4. unicode --> ANSI(multibyte)
    nLenOfANSI = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, uni_wchar, nLenOfUni, pszOut, nLenOfANSI, NULL, NULL);
    pszOut[nLenOfANSI] = 0;
    resultString = pszOut;
    delete[] uni_wchar;
    delete[] pszOut;
    return resultString;
}


  [1]: https://sunny-green-970.notion.site/Error-ea96fbef0ea64e1bb1fd966699657547
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK8m0.png
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to use low-level sockets to connect to the database. Use the MySQL Connector library.

Comment: I use MySQL connector C++ 8.0 and finish project setting too.